# Issue installing ModX Revolution

Tags: installation, zip, modx, modx-revolution

I am trying to install version 2.2 of ModX Revolution. Everything goes fine up until the last step where I get this error:

```
    The install failed because MODX could not unpack the 
/public_html/core/packages/core.transport.zip package. Make sure that the 
/public_html/core/packages/core.transport.zip file exists and is writable, and that you have made the 
/public_html/core/packages/ directory writable.
```

I have checked and the directory is writable and the file core.transport.zip does exists and is also writable.

Can anyone tell me whats going on?

Comment: Not really a solution but I went back to version 2.1.3 and its happy

Comment: Is this a upgrade of fresh re-install? 2.2.4 is the newest version. Uploading the entire content on your ftp should work in 99.9% of all cases.

Comment: @OptimusCrime its a fresh install of 2.2.4.... I guessing even that even though they are unzipped the install still tries to unzip the files itself

Answer (score 5):

Do you have a folder 'core' next to the zip file? if yes, just make it (and **every file within** it) writable. Worked for me..